# How to compare a middle element of a list with a certain number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list of 12 items, I need to check if the number 6(middle number) is greater than let's say 9. How can I achieve this?
I've managed to write a code that finds the middle value, now I need to compare that value to a certain number.

```
def eat(list):
    return print(int(len(list)/2))
    


print(eat([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question, because this seems completely obvious. You know how to fetch the number.  Just take `m = list[len(list)//2]` and do what you want with `m`.  By the way, DO NOT name your own variable `list`, because that hides the Python type name.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want it to be a part of function, not a variable. I will try to make a second parameter.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to.  You don't need a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the number in the middle of a list by getting half of the total size of the list itself.

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3]
middle = myList[len(myList) // 2] - 1 # => 2
```

From there, it is a simple arithmetic check to see if it is greater than the number you want to compare it with.

```py
def isMiddleGreaterThan(the_list, num):
    return the_list[len(the_list) // 2] > num

print(isMiddleGreaterThan([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)) # True, as 4 > 3.
```